# How to add custom text to success rspec message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm generating some automatic specs and I would like to have a custom success message with the times that the expectation was success.
For example, I would like a report like:

```
Opportunity
  .rating_info
    where the real estate kind is Monoambiente
      and there aren't assigned values
        is 0
      when there are multiple combinations
        is has the expected value(run 45 different combinations)
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems that [it's possible through use of a custom formatter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rspec/rspec-core/master/spec/rspec/core/formatters/progress_formatter_spec.rb):

```
class PedrazaFormatter < BaseTextFormatter
        Formatters.register self, :example_passed

        def init(times = 0)
          self.times = times
        end

        def example_passed(_notification)
          output.print "Test was successful #{self.times} times"
        end
end
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have further concerns.

Comment: @AugustoPedraza if this helped you, would you care to click the green checkmark?